# How to solve Sendgrid nodemailer error with with 4078 code

Tags: javascript, node.js, sendgrid, nodemailer, mailtrap

I write email class:

```
const pug = require('pug')
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const htmlToText = require('html-to-text');

module.exports = class Email{
   constructor(user, url) {
      this.to = user.email;
      this.firstName = user.name.split(' ')[0];
      this.url = url;
      this.from = `Feruz Atamuradow <${process.env.EMAIL_FROM}>`;
   }

   newTransport() {
      if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
         return nodemailer.createTransport({
         service: 'SendGrid',
         auth: {
            user: process.env.SENDGRID_USERNAME,
            pass: process.env.SENDGRID_PASSWORD
         }
         });
      }

      return nodemailer.createTransport({
         host: process.env.EMAIL_HOST,
         port: process.env.EMAIL_PORT,
         auth: {
         user: process.env.EMAIL_USERNAME,
         pass: process.env.EMAIL_PASSWORD
         },
         tls:{
            rejectUnauthorized:false
         } // and  try this without 

      });
  }

   async send(template, subject) {
      const html = pug.renderFile(`${__dirname}/../views/email/${template}.pug`, {
         firstName: this.firstName,
         url: this.url,
         subject
      });

      const mailOptions = {
         from: this.from,
         to: this.to,
         subject,
         html,
         text: htmlToText.fromString(html)
      }
      
      await this.newTransport().sendMail(mailOptions)

   }
   async sendWelcome() {
      await this.send('welcome', 'Welcome to the Natours Family!');
   }
   async sendPasswordReset() {
      await this.send('passwordReset', 'Your password reset token (valid for only 10 minutes)')
   }
}
```

But I get only this error and I didnt understand this error. What mean and how to solve this

> error: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 3.209.246.195:2525
> at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1146:16) {
> errno: -4078,
> code: 'ESOCKET',
> syscall: 'connect',
> address: '3.209.246.195',
> port: 2525,
> command: 'CONN'
> }

and I get this 'production' error:

> error: Error: Message failed: 550 The from address does not match a
> verified Sender Identity. Mail cannot be sent until this error is
> resolved. Visit
> https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/sender-identity/
> to see the Sender Identity requirements
> at SMTPConnection._formatError (C:\Users\feruz\Desktop\complete\4-natours\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:784:19)
> at SMTPConnection._actionSMTPStream (C:\Users\feruz\Desktop\complete\4-natours\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:1674:34)
> at SMTPConnection. (C:\Users\feruz\Desktop\complete\4-natours\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:1152:22)
> at SMTPConnection._processResponse (C:\Users\feruz\Desktop\complete\4-natours\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:947:20)
> at SMTPConnection._onData (C:\Users\feruz\Desktop\complete\4-natours\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:749:14)
> at TLSSocket.SMTPConnection._onSocketData (C:\Users\feruz\Desktop\complete\4-natours\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:189:44)
> at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
> at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:309:12)
> at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:284:9)
> at TLSSocket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:223:10) {   code: 'EMESSAGE',   response: '550 The from address does not match a
> verified Sender Identity. Mail cannot be sent until this error is
> resolved. Visit
> https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/sender-identity/
> to see the Sender Identity requirements',   responseCode: 550,
> command: 'DATA' }

Comment: Yeah it is work for process.env.NODE_ENV!=='production'. but cant send email in sendgrid

Answer (score 0):

IP, port that you use is incorrect or service is not running at port 2525 of 3.209.246.195. You should check it again.

Check connection: ping 3.209.246.195

Check service (port): telnet 3.209.246.195 2525